# npm with java - throwing errors

Tags: java, node.js, npm

I need to install a java based package with NPM. I also can't do `npm install java`

When I try to install said package, I get the following error:

> ld: warning: directory not found for option
>   '-L/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server'
>   ld: library not found for -ljvm

What is `-ljvm`? I cannot find anything on google about this flag or on Stack Overflow.

Has anyone else seen this error? How did they fix it?

More details: I'm on MacOSX Sierra, java version 9.0.1, npm version 5.6.0

Comment: does your system have a JDK installed ? at a terminal issue ...  java  -version ... does it match the jdk you have listed  ... the command ld is a dynamic linker ... part of the build infrastructure tools used to compile source

Comment: java 9.0.1
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)

Comment: Update your question to say which OS you are on ... on linux with c and c++ compilers and helper packages  and  nodejs and java installed your above `npm install java` runs fine ... if on linux apt package `build-essential` does a long way to jack up a box to enable such incantations ... if OSX similarily assure your machine compiles c and c++ correctly as that's the glue node uses to strap on other languages ... the -l as in -ljvm is how c and c++ compiler/linker command specifies a necessary library

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall [jdk](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk9-downloads-3848520.html) or use [the previous version](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).

I have `libjvm.dylib` in the directory, what does `-ljvm` stand for.